# Tensorflow tf.map_fn over ragged tensor fails with object of type 'RaggedTensor' has no len

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0, ragged-tensors

[This Tensorflow doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/ragged_tensor) gives this example of using `tf.map_fn` on ragged tensors which works for Tensorflow 2.4.1 and above:

```
digits = tf.ragged.constant([[3, 1, 4, 1], [], [5, 9, 2], [6], []])
print(tf.map_fn(tf.math.square, digits))
```

However the following example results in error "object of type 'RaggedTensor' has no len" when run in Tensorflow 2.4.1 or Tensorflow 2.5:

```
import tensorflow as tf

X=tf.ragged.constant([[1.,2.],[3.,4.,5.]], dtype=tf.float32)

@tf.function
def powerX(i):
    global X
    return X**i

Y = tf.map_fn(powerX, tf.range(3, dtype=tf.float32))
```

Is there a way to make this work?  I don't understand the error being thrown.  In general I am trying to get full parallelism by mapping a user defined function which has only Tensorflow operations over a ragged tensor with results being ragged tensors.

Answer (score 3):

`tf.map_fn` requires an output signature. I'm not sure why it can't infer this from the input but that's a question for the tensorflow people.
The following code will work for you.

```
import tensorflow as tf

X=tf.ragged.constant([[1.,2.],[3.,4.,5.]], dtype=tf.float32)

@tf.function
def powerX(i):
    global X
    return X**i
signature = tf.type_spec_from_value(powerX(X))
Y = tf.map_fn(powerX, tf.range(3, dtype=tf.float32),fn_output_signature=signature)
```